# List of formatted strings based on the elements of two lists

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list

I am trying to join two lists in such a manner in Python 2.7:

```
a = ['x','y','z']
b = [1,2,3]
```

and the end result should be:

```
c=['x1','y2','z3']
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 6):

```
c = [p + str(q) for p, q in zip(a, b)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of concatenating the string, it is even better to use [**`string.format`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function. You can also use it with [**`itertools.starmap`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) with the [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) version of the lists as:

```
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> a = ['x','y','z']
>>> b = [1,2,3]

>>> list(starmap("{}{}".format, zip(a, b)))
['x1', 'y2', 'z3']

# Note: `starmap` returns an iterator. If you want to iterate this value
# only once, then there is no need to type-case it to `list`
```

Or you can use it with the legendary *list comprehensions* as:

```
>>> ['{}{}'.format(x, y) for x, y in zip(a, b)]
['x1', 'y2', 'z3']
```

With `format`, you don't have to explicitly type-cast your `int` to `str`. Also it is simpler to change the format of your desired strings in the lists. For example:

```
>>> ['{} -- {}'.format(x, y) for x, y in zip(a, b)]
['x -- 1', 'y -- 2', 'z -- 3']
```

Here's a **generalized solution to format `n` lists**:

```
>>> my_lists = [
        ['a', 'b', 'c'],   # List 1
        [1, 2, 3],         # List 2
        # ...              # few more lists 
        ['x', 'y', 'z']    # List `N`
    ]

# Using `itertools.starmap`
>>> list(starmap(("{}"*len(my_lists)).format, zip(*my_lists)))
['a1x', 'b2y', 'c3z']

# Using list comprehension
>>> [('{}'*len(my_lists)).format(*x) for x in zip(*my_lists)]
['a1x', 'b2y', 'c3z']
```

Comment: I do prefer `format` as well. It even makes using maps a lot nicer. checkout `import itertools; itertools.starmap("{}{}".format, zip(a, b))`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Nice usecase of `starmap`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailled and fast answer. The thing is my list is quite a long one. It has 7000 items in both of the list. When I used you proposed method it perfectly does it but only the half of the items. Do you have an idea what could go wrong?

Comment: @SavasAdiloglu possibly your one of the list is having lesser items than the other list. try checking length of both using `len(your_list)`

Comment: Any negative side effects using `itertools.zip_longest` with `fillvalue = ''` instead of `zip`?

Comment: the only side effect is that you will be getting empty value for the extra elements in your list. If that's ok with you, please go ahead with `zip_longest` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one as well, based on @SilverSlash's solution, using the `map` function:

```
a = ['x','y','z']
b = [1,2,3]

c = list(map(''.join, zip(a, map(str, b))))
print(c)
```

Output:

```
['x1', 'y2', 'z3']
```

Comment: You can also simplify it to `list(map(''.join, zip(a, map(str, b))))`